# User ranking query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
**user**
id, name, points
```

Can you suggest me how to compose a query to get user place by points.

For example:

```
1, 'David', 5
2, 'Dmitry', 10
3, 'Monica', 15
4, 'Jeniffer', 7
5, 'Andy', 12
```

User 'Monica' has a 1st place based on points, 'Jeniffer' - 4th place and so on.

Thanks for advice!

**EDIT**

I want a query like:

```
SELECT rank FROM user ... WHERE id = 3;
rank |
1

SELECT rank FROM user ... WHERE id = 5;
rank |
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
SELECT
   id,rank, name,point 
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        name,
        point,  
        @rank := @rank + 1 as rank        
    FROM (
      SELECT * from tblA ORDER by point desc) As a, 
    (SELECT @rank := 0) AS vars      

) T 
WHERE id=1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/581fc/9

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user order by points desc
```

Comment: Nope.. I want result of query should be the number of rank. SELECT rank FROM user ........ WHERE id = 1 should return '1'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t.rank from (
      select @i := @i + 1 as rank, id, name, points
        from MyUser x,(SELECT @i:=0) foo 
    order by x.points desc) T
 where T.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `points` DESC;
```

If you wanna get the first rank holder alone, you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `points` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @rank := 0;
select *, (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank
from (select * from user order by points desc) x
where id = 3
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from (select * from customer order by points desc) x where id = 3' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
select *,RANK() over(order by points desc) as rnk from user_ 
)
select rnk [rank] from cte where id=3
```